# Set contents of div to lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I'm creating a keyword search for a project. so to make sure it's not case sensitive, I'm setting the search value and the content to lowercase before the comparison is made. This is where I'm at:
`self.contentSelected = jQuery('.policies_container .lof-element .lof-inner a').html();`

```
jQuery('.policies_container .lof-element .lof-inner a :contains("' + self.term + '")').each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace(new RegExp(self.term, 'g'), '<span class="highlight">' + self.term + '</span>'));
                    jQuery(this)
                        .find('.highlight')
                        .fadeIn(self.fadeSpeed);

                    jQuery(".highlight").each(function() {
                        if(jQuery(this).parent().is(":hidden")) {
                            jQuery(this).closest(".lof-element").slideDown();
                            jQuery(this).closest(".lof-toggler").addClass("active_acc");

                            self.targetOffset = jQuery(".highlight:first-child").offset().top;
                            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: self.targetOffset}, self.scrollSpeed);
                        } 
                    });
                });
```

so this second line here

`jQuery('.policies_container .lof-element .lof-inner a :contains("' + self.term + '")').each(function() {`

I'm looking for the syntax needed to se that .lof-inner content to lowercase while still applying a :contains selector.

Any help, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

use a CSS attribute :

```
text-transform:lowercase;
```

or use javascript function :

```
variable.toLowerCase();
```

in second method (javascript) you need to convert both source and search expression to lowercase before passing it to `contains()` method.

Comment: `text-transform` won't affect the text nodes that JavaScript accesses.

Answer (score 1):

`:contains()` is case sensitive.

You could use a regex and `filter()` to assist...

```
elements.filter(function() {
   return $(this).text().match(/\bword\b/i);
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks Alex, after a bit of search myself I discovered how that might be the way to go. Though I'm still a little unsure about the implementation of that in my example :S

Comment: @Shane If you pass a set of elements to this, it will return the ones which text nodes contain `word` (separated either side by a word boundary).